# how can i run code that need a long time without the computer sleep or exit user?

Tags: c++

I wrote a code in C ++ that requires a long run time (days-weeks)
But when I run it after a little while the computer goes to sleep or it leaves the user or the screen turns off
Is there a way that the program will continue to run? Function maybe?

Comment: Change the power settings on your computer to never go to sleep. Look it up on google for your specific OS.

Comment: If this should be save with respect to the user, you should constantly update some files on the computer which allow the program to pick up where it stopped last time. Maybe something like status_i.dat, with i being some iteration number. You want to keep at least two files, since one file could be corrupted due to being only halfway written. Another solution is to get access to a cluster.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you need to use SetThreadExecutionState.
From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.